# What are the solution for this system?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I have a congruence system of equations :

$a\equiv-1\pmod 7$

$a\equiv0\pmod{13}$

what are the possible values for $a$ knowing that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

i tried to put $13k$ in the first equation and solve for $k$ but i get stuck.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: What do you get by pluggin the 13k in the first equation?

Comment: Actually, No i didn't hear of that before.

Comment: @Phicar $13k\equiv -k \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 7$

Comment: where do you get the last k? you should obtain $-k\equiv -1 \pmod 7$ Ah 0k..you were editing it :P. What does it means to have that equivalence?(by definition)

Comment: Yes multiply both sides by $-1$

Comment: That's the problem i don't know what i'm doing :).

Comment: ah 0k..$a\equiv b \pmod n$ means that for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ a=n*q+b. So, in your problem, $k=7q+1$ for some q. but $a =13k$ so how is a?

Comment: it seems to be $a=13q^{'}$, right ?

Comment: nop, just plug the two equations you have and you will see :)

Comment: Well, $a=13(7q+1)=91q+13$

Comment: @Phicar can't we say that $91q+13=13q^{'}$ ?

Comment: yes, and q moves freely en $\mathbb{Z}$ because it does not matter in the equivalences. So those are your answers

Comment: @Phicar You mean $13q^{'}$ is true ?

Comment: you can name it like that if you want, but $q'$ is the same as the k you have.

Comment: Yes, I mean if i work with $13k$ does it going to work, actually the first value witch is $13(0)=0$ doesn't $\equiv -1 \pmod7$ ?

Comment: Ah ok ok, $q^{'}\not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Nop, the one that moves freely in $\mathbb{Z}$ is q not k. You expressed k in terms of q.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve

$$\begin{align}
a\equiv-1&\pmod 7 \\
a\equiv0&\pmod{13}.
\end{align}$$

To do this, we will analyze what these mean in turn. $a \equiv -1 \bmod 7$ means that $7 \mid (a+1)$, or that $a = 7n -1$ for some $n$. Let's take this to the next congruence equation.

$a = 7n-1 \equiv 0 \bmod 13$, or that $7n \equiv 1 \bmod 13$. What does this make $n$? It means that $n \equiv 2 \bmod 13$ (because it's the inverse of $7 \bmod 13$). So $n = 2 + 13m$ for some $m$. Putting this back into our $a$ expression, we see that $a = 7(2 + 13m) - 1 = 13 + 91m$, or equivalently that $a \equiv 13 \bmod 91$.

Let's go back and check. $13 \equiv 0 \bmod 13$, so that's good, and $13 \equiv -1 \bmod 7$, so it all works out. Thus $a \equiv 13 \bmod 91$ is the solution.

*Aside: In the comments, the Chinese Remainder Theorem was mentioned. The Chinese Remainder Theorem is a statement about these solutions, when they exist, and how many there are. I [wrote a post](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1232) on the Chinese Remainder Theorem for my students one summer which you might appreciate.*

Comment: That's ok but actually i can't understand the one of $n\equiv2\pmod{13}$, doesn't n moves freely in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?, and why it is $\equiv 2 \pmod{13}$ ?